# Why can I put the limit sign in equations

Tags: calculus, limits

Why can I put the limit sign in both sides of an equation?

Is there a rigorous way to prove that if:

$f(x)=g(x)$

Then

$\lim \limits_{x\to x_0}f(x) =\lim \limits_{x\to x_0}g(x)$

Thanks.

Comment: If you mean that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all values of $x,$ then $g$ is really just another name for the function $f.$ In other words, you're taking the limit of the same function on both sides of the equation. It would quite weird if taking the limit of a function on one side of an equation gave you one answer and then you again took the limit at the same point of the same function and got a different answer.

Comment: For each $x \neq x_0$, $f(x)=g(x)$. So when you pick any $\epsilon>0$, the same $\delta$ works

Comment: $f(x) - g(x) = 0$, so  $\lim_{x \to x_{0}} f(x) - g(x) = 0 \Rightarrow   \lim_{x \to x_{0}} f(x) -   \lim_{x \to x_{0}} g(x) = 0  \Rightarrow  \lim_{x \to x_{0}} f(x) = \lim_{x \to x_{0}} g(x)$.

Comment: In fact, it's sufficient to have $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in (a, x_0) \cup (x_0, b)$ for some $a, b$ where $a < x_0$ and $x_0 < b$.

Comment: If $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ then there is no way of distinguishing them numerically, hence any operation on one will produce identical results to the same operation on the other.

Comment: This is one the basic tenets of the concept of equality. If $A=B$ then both $A, B$ are indistinguishable from each other as far as their usage in mathematics is concerned. One should not desire to prove such things, but understand that it is just the meaning of equality.

Comment: On the other hand this is a trivial theorem which one should prove (and without those nasty $\epsilon, \delta $) : If $f, g$ are functions such that $f(x) =g(x) $ in some neighborhood of $x_{0}$ except possibly at $x_{0}$ then $\lim_{x\to x_{0}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to x_{0}}g(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if $f(x)=g(x)$, then $f(x)=g(x)=f(x)$.

Therefore, we have $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0}[f(x)]=\lim_{x \to x_0}[g(x)]$, because we have an identical expression under a different name.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that 
$$\forall x \in (x_0-\eta,x_0+\eta) \;\;F(x)=0$$
and let us prove that

$$L=\lim_{x\to x_0} F (x)=0.$$

suppose $L\ne 0$.
take $\epsilon=|L|/2$.

$\exists a>0  : \forall x\in (x_0-a,x_0+a) $ 
$$|F (x)-L|< | L|/2$$
but $F (x)=0$ then
$$|L|<|L|/2$$
which is not possible.